# Storing data from dynamic forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, dynamic-forms

I am working on dynamic form generator. Someone can create fields like: string, text, boolean, number, file etc.

**Are there any gems or guidelines for storing data from such dynamic forms?**

I mean I can create a number of tables for each datatype, or I can store all of them as a `TEXT` with flag wich type it should be converted.

**UPD**

or I'd better use nosql here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Mongodb is a right choice for this application, since it doesn't enforce any schema, its a good choice for arbitrary data.

As well, it does support all the datatype you have expected. so it is easy.

Have a form collection which looks like this (Ruby Mongoid code)

```
  class XForm
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

       field :name, :type => String
       field :user, :type => BSON::ObjectId     

       embeds_many :formfields
  end
```

and

```
 class Formfields
  include Mongoid::Document

     field :name, :type => String
     field :kind, :type => String
     #field :value, :type => String -> dont add it in formfields, make it dynamic sine the type varies

  embedded_in :xform
  end
```

To add value field as  a dynamic field, you need to enable `allow_dynamic_fields: true` in mongoid.yml

and create a new field like this

```
  form = XForm.new(:name=>'test form',:user => current_user.id)
   #for integer field
   form.formfields << Formfields.new(:name => "Age",:kind=>"Integer", :value => 21)
   #for bool field
   form.formfields << Formfields.new(:name => "isMarried",:kind=>"Boolean",:value => true)
   #for string field
   form.formfields << Formfields.new(:name => "name",:kind=>"String",:value => "ram")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will store forms structure separate from form values. Because many people will fill forms. And I prefer to use MongoMapper :). Anyway, thanks for your approach, it is useful

Answer (score 2):

I like this approach.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  [:field_1, :field_2, :field_3].each do |method|
    define_method method do
      workable_arbitrary_content[method]
    end

    define_method "#{method}=" do |value|
      data = workable_arbitrary_content.merge(method => value)
      self.arbitrary_content = YAML.dump(data)
    end
  end

  private
    def workable_arbitrary_content
      YAML.load(arbitrary_content || "") || {}
    end
end
```

I this case you create 3 virtual fields that is being saved as YAML.
Create a field in the `users` called `arbitrary_content` that is of type *text*.

Here are some specs for the code above.

```
describe User do
  context "virtual fields" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = User.new
    end

    it "should be able to handle strings" do
      @user.field_1 = "Data"
      @user.field_1.should eq("Data")
    end

    it "should be able to handle integers" do
      @user.field_2 = 1
      @user.field_2.should eq(1)
    end

    it "should be able to handle symbols" do
      @user.field_3 = :symbol
      @user.field_3.should eq(:symbol)
    end

    it "should be possible to override a field" do
      @user.field_3 = :symbol
      @user.field_3 = "string"

      @user.field_3.should eq("string")
    end

    it "should be possible to set more then one field" do
      @user.field_1 = :symbol
      @user.field_2 = "string"

      @user.field_1.should eq(:symbol)
      @user.field_2.should eq("string")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting approach, that shows that we should use NoSQL here fore storing data structure :). Thanks!

Comment: @fl00r Exactly :) I think that NoSQL is the shit in this case.